# Corflag permission issue

Tags: command-prompt, x86-64

I'm trying to use corflags to set the bitness and/or read the assembly info of a dll. I keep getting CF001 and CF002 errors. It seems like just a simple permission switch I need to configure. Not sure what I miss... Can you someone point me to the right place so I can grant myself permission? Thanks in advance!

1. What I did trying to solve the permission issue:

   - ran the vs dev command prompt in admin mode
   - gave myself full control to the folder
   - gave myself full control to dll
2. Exact error message: (depending whether I try to read or write, I
   get one of the following errors)

   - corflags : error CF001 : Could not open file for writing
   - corflags: error CF002 : Could not open file for reading

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved: The command path must point to the same location as the dll before running corflag command line.